# count occurrences of number by column in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame I want to count how often a number appears in a column for each column

```
     a   b   c   d   e
0    2   3   1   5   4
1    1   3   2   5   4
2    1   3   2   5   4
3    2   4   1   5   3
4    2   4   1   5   3
```

This is my code that does not work

```
def equalsOne(x):
    x[x.columns == 1].sum()

df1.apply(equalOne(), axis = 1)
```

Here is the desired output

```
a 2
b 0
c 3
d 0
e 0
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do:

```
(df==1).sum()
```

`df==1` gives:

```
       a      b      c      d      e
0  False  False   True  False  False
1   True  False  False  False  False
2   True  False  False  False  False
3  False  False   True  False  False
4  False  False   True  False  False
```

and the `sum()` treats `False` as `0` and `True` as `1`.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick

```
df1[df1 == 1].count()
```