# How often 0-9 repeat in leftmost digit of index of one dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, frequency

I was wondering if we can count how often 0-9 repeat in leftmost digit of `index` of certain panda dataframe :

```
             A          B           C
0   -56.343656        NaN -418.540483
10  -87.577880 -16.061497         NaN
20         NaN -15.337254         NaN
40  -67.462841        NaN -431.924830
50  -63.377158 -28.260790         NaN
60         NaN -22.996095         NaN
130  11.569845        NaN -307.034737
180  11.398947  -1.793530         NaN
```

I've extracted the indexes of those columns have nan including leading 0:

```
000
010
020
040
050
060
130
180
```

and try to store extracted indexes in csv file. then I even tried to put them in data frame again base this principle leftmost digit could be [0-7] the 2nd leftmost digit could be [0-59] and the last one could be [0-9999] and store in in csv file to further process on just `'section'` column which represents leftmost digit column.

My scripts are following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('D:\SOF.TXT', header=None)
id_set = df[df.index % 4 == 0].astype('int').values
A = df[df.index % 4 == 1].values
B = df[df.index % 4 == 2].values
C = df[df.index % 4 == 3].values

data = {'A': A[:,0], 'B': B[:,0], 'C': C[:,0]}
#main_data contains all the data
main_data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B','C'], index = id_set[:,0])  


main_data[np.isinf(main_data)] = np.nan    # convert inf to nan
main_data_nan = main_data[main_data.isnull().any(axis=1)]   # extract sub data frame
print(main_data_nan)
# to fix 3 digits of index in start
new_index = [str(x).zfill(3) for x in main_data_nan.index]
main_data_nan.index = new_index
#print all data includes nan values in .csv file
main_data_nan.to_csv('nan_data.csv', na_rep='NaN')   # export
#print just especial column that includes nan values in .csv file including id_set or indexes
main_data_nan['C'].to_csv('nan_datatemp.csv', na_rep='NaN')
#print all id_set which is index in data frame has nan values
for i in range(len(main_data_nan)):
    print (main_data_nan.index[i])


dff = pd.read_csv("D:\nan_datatemp.csv")
cycle, section, cell = [], [], []
for i in range(9999):
    for j in range(8):
        for k in range(60):
            cycle.append(i)
            section.append(j)
            cell.append(k)
dfff = {'Section':section, 'Cell':cell, 'Cycle':cycle}
dffff = pd.DataFrame(dfff, columns=['Section','Cell', 'Cycle'], index = id_set[:,0])
dffff.to_csv('exit_id_det.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

I'm not sure the answer of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27140860/count-occurrences-of-number-by-column-in-pandas-data-frame) could be fulfill my answer by applying `(df==X).sum()` on leftmost digit index like:

```
(df==0).sum()
(df==1).sum()
(df==2).sum()
(df==3).sum()
(df==4).sum()
(df==5).sum()
(df==6).sum()
(df==7).sum()
```

and even using `main_data_nan.isnull().sum().sum()` computing percentage of frequency occurrence of them
My desire results should be like:

**index**         ----> **frequency**  --->  **percentage**
`0`00 ---->    `0`: 6 times ---->       `0`: 75%  in total
`0`10 ---->    `1`: 2 times ---->       `1`: 25%  in total
`0`20 ---->       2: 0 times  ---->           2: 0%   in total
`0`40 ---->       3: 0 times  ---->           3: 0%   in total
`0`50 ---->       4: 0 times  ---->           4: 0%   in total
`0`60 ---->       5: 0 times  ---->           5: 0%   in total
`1`30 ---->       6: 0 times  ---->           6: 0%   in total
`1`80 ---->       7: 0 times  ---->           7: 0%   in total

Here below is my dataset sample: [dataset sample DL link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=45654156408138658207)

Comment: Could you clarify your question and include an example of what you want exactly? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @JoePatten I'm interested in **frequency occurrence** of leftmost digit of extracted `index` from those columns that have NaN in panda dataframe eg.   **0**00 ,**0**10 ,**0**20 ,**0**40 ,**0**50,**0**60,**1**30,,**1**80              **0**: 6 times      75% in total and **1**: 2 times      25% in total

Comment: So I'm assuming that the indexes < 1000, so I won't be seeing an index like 2010?

Comment: @JoePatten My case **indexes format** could be maximum [0-7] [0-59] [0-9999] it means I could have :     `0` 29 3333 , `7` 59 9999  but I'm interested in `leftmost` digit ones but if you mean **numbers of indexes** would be < 1000? it's  is not right perhaps I have 2000 NaN values in dataset which their indexes  total numbers would be 2000

Comment: Are you trying to extract the left most digit for each of those sections? (in this case section, cell and cycle)? ]For example if you have the number  `006888` then `section=0`, `cell=0`, `cycle=8`?

Comment: exactly but in your example would be `section=0` `cell=0` `cycle=6888` as I mentioned left most digit could be [0-7] as Section, 2nd leftmost digit could be [0-59] as cell and finally the last leftmost digit could be [0-9999] as cycle, your assumption was right for this index `068` actually as long as they are single number like 0 6 8 they'll be shown as  `068` I mean we don't have this `0 06 08`. To sum it up 1st leftmost digit is always single digit, 2nd leftmost digit could be double digit after passed 9 and turn over to 10, 11, ..,59. The last digit could be increased to 4 digit too.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new column named `index` from index, then find condense your dataframe so you have only columns observations that contain null values. Then count the left most digit for each section.

```
import collections

df['index'] = df.index
null_data = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
cycle_left = collections.Counter(null_data['index']//100%10)
cell_left = collections.Counter(null_data['index']//10000%10)
section_left = collections.Counter(null_data['index']//100000%10)
```

The output will be a dictionary where the keys are the left most digits, and the values are the frequencies for each digit.

Now, let's assume that you have null values at indexes `427888, 101, 6123456`.

Example Output:

```
Counter({1: 1, 8: 1, 4: 1})     #cycle_left
Counter({2: 2, 0: 1})           #cell_left
Counter({0: 1, 4: 1, 1: 1})     #section_left
```

You could also use `.value_counts()` in the last step to get a series containing frequencies (the index would be the left most digit and the value would be the frequency for that digit).

```
df['index'] = df.index
null_data = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
cycle_left = (null_data['index']//100%10).value_counts()
cell_left = (null_data['index']//10000%10).value_counts()
section_left = (null_data['index']//100000%10).value_counts()
```

Example Output:

```
#cycle_left
4    1
1    1
8    1
Name: index, dtype: int64

#cell_left
2    2
0    1
Name: index, dtype: int64

#section_left
1    1
4    1
0    1
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi Joe, by changing to `df['index'] = int(df.index[i])` if you mean I've just got below result regarding my dataframe which is right but what about another one also 1 repeated 2 times!
0    6
Name: index, dtype: int64 but it doesn't work for cell and cycle not at all! it would be nice if you follow and apply my dataset to see what I see then we might achieve the goal quickly. thanks man!

Comment: Can you put your dataset into a better format? Post the dictionary of the dataset if you can (by using `df.to_dict()`).

Comment: I'm afraid it's unnecessary otherwise I can find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716616/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: man would u do me a favor and have a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489201/how-can-make-a-dataset-of-elements-of-matrices-in-dataframe) You might have an idea?